# Share HTML content between pages

Tags: html

I'm sure this is an FAQ and probably answered many times on Google but I'm struggling to work out what to search on.

I want to write a bit of HTML on one page and then include a reference to the same HTML on another page. The pages will be in different sites but the same site collection. The requirement is a master "Hints & tips" page which contains thinks like this (although typically the tip will be longer like a paragraph):

Use www.tinyurl.com to shorten long links
Ctrl-0 resets zoom to 100% in Internet Explorer
Ctrl-F5 completely refreshes the page

When a new tip is added, the web master might want to put a copy on the home page as "tip of the day". I don't want to duplicate the text, I want to reference the HTML on the master hints & tip page.

I'm very familiar with DotNetNuke and this is bread & butter functionality in there. You simply insert a reference to an existing HTML module.

Maybe web parts are the solution here but not sure if you can reference on web part in one site from another site. It's a publishing web site BTW.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is called "Reusable content". The following links will help you on your journey to wisdom:

- [Use reusable content](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-reusable-content-HA010163838.aspx)
- [SharePoint Reusable Content](http://erikswenson.blogspot.de/2009/08/sharepoint-reusable-content.html)
- [SharePoint 2010 Reusable Content](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1112)

Bear in mind that Reusable Content is only meant for HTML content or other content and can only be used on certain pages - just give it a go and see whether it fulfills your needs.

Comment: Thanks - for me the problem went away by me moving on from the company but thanks for the reply. I can't mark it as the correct answer as I'm unable to clarify but it sounds like it's barking up the right tree

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Re-usable content you can use a Content Editor WebPart (CEWP)

Do not put any Content in it, but set the reference Link, it will execute the HTML (including *script* tags> from that file inline... depending on what to do you may want to wait till everything is loaded

[image]

Content needs to come from an accesible location, so can span Site Collections.
You can call scripts from another domain, provided you have tackled all the CORS issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can't vote for the answer but I planned to answer the same thing before reading moontear's post.

Reusable content is a powerful function and I used it at large for a big SP project, it did the job !