# Reusing Content (HTML/CSS)

Tags: css, html, content

In [another question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112546/dynamically-display-list-from-menu-selection) I asked about dynamically calling Lists to a page(Web Part) via a menu. A problem which I have not solved, and has since become more complicated by the following. If I create all the pages required for those lists and manually enter that menu in each page I have a tremendous problem if the menu ever needs changing (it will), I have to change each instance of the menu on each page.

In a [normal non-SharePoint world](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/showfile_c.asp?filename=try_webpages_cs_002) this is easy. This is the precise functionality I want.

```
<html>
<body>
@RenderPage("header.aspx")
@RenderPage("menu.aspx")
CONTENT!
@RenderPage("buttons.aspx")
</body>
</html>
```

Then, whenever any of the "Render" components need changing I just have to edit the one file.

Oh, but [it's easy in SharePoint you say](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/share-html-content-between-pages)? I do not have access to the Reusable Content functionality with the SharePoint installed here - 2010 with no access to Designer.

Thanks for any help.

So, I've tried using the Page Viewer Web Part and it ALMOST works. The file is a HTML/CSS menu. It only partially loads, as in the menu items are there but the drop downs do not work. Is there somewhere I can be informed on the limitations of the Page Viewer Web Part, or something I need to know about using it for sharing code on a site?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by exporting my Content Editor Web Parts from a master page. Then it is uploaded to each page instead of changing each file. It's not exactly what I want but there is an efficiency benefit.

Better solution on top of that efficiency:

The fix I used for this was to put the menu in a html document and link to that in a Content Editor Web part. Oddly, it renders better that way than if I dump the html in the Content Editor Web part with the exact same code. Now I only have the one menu.htm to edit and all the Web parts that link to it are updated.